# interactive slider in .Rmd file for Regression

Tags: r, shiny, regression

I try to code my first interactive .Rmd file:

I just want to show the interaction in a linear regression x~y by

```
 y(x)= a*x + b
```

I just want to take two sliders:

one for b and one for a

my code is until now:

````
--- 
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

## some text...

*some more text

<br><br>

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r, echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warnings=FALSE}

mietspiegel <- read.table("http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/service/datenarchiv/miete/miete03.asc", header=TRUE)
mieten_regression <- lm(mietspiegel$nm ~ mietspiegel$wfl)
mieten_regression$coefficients

b <- mieten_regression$coefficients[1]      # Coefficient No. 1   Intercept
a <- mieten_regression$coefficients[2]      # Coefficient No. 2   mietspiegel$wfl

# Slider ...
inputPanel(sliderInput("b", "Coefficient No. 1 Intercept", min = 0, max = 2000, step = 1, value = b), 
sliderInput("a", "Coefficient No. 2 Wohnflaeche", min = 0, max = 200, step = 10, value = a),
actionButton("sample", "Resample"))

# Scatterplott
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mietspiegel, 
aes(y=nm, x=wfl)) +
geom_abline(intercept = b, slope = a, colour = "red") + # Add inear regression line     
geom_point(shape=1) + # Use hollow circles
xlab("Fläche") +
ylab("Price")

```
````

I don't know how to use the slider input correctly. I want for my linear regression line a slider for a and a slider for b so that you can input there your coefficents intercept (b) and  mietspiegel$wfl (a) are and see the new regression line after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make `geom_abline` dependent on your sliders you should wrap the ggplot part into `renderPlot` function and then set the parameter `a` to `input$a` and the parameter `b` to `input$b`. (You access the value of the given widget with `input$id`)

```
renderPlot({ 
  library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(mietspiegel, 
         aes(y=nm, x=wfl)) +
    geom_abline(intercept = input$b, slope = input$a, colour = "red") + # Add inear regression line     
    geom_point(shape=1) + # Use hollow circles
    xlab("Fläche") +
    ylab("Price")
})
```

---

**EDITED:** I added answers to further questions as comments in the code below

````
--- 
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

## some text...

*some more text

<br><br>

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r, echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warnings=FALSE}

mietspiegel <- read.table("http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/service/datenarchiv/miete/miete03.asc", header=TRUE)
mieten_regression <- lm(mietspiegel$nm ~ mietspiegel$wfl)
mieten_regression$coefficients

b <- mieten_regression$coefficients[1]      # Coefficient No. 1   Intercept
a <- mieten_regression$coefficients[2]      # Coefficient No. 2   mietspiegel$wfl



 # Slider ...

inputPanel(
  sliderInput("b", "Coefficient No. 1 Intercept", min = 0, max = 200, step = 10, value = b),

  sliderInput("a", "Coefficient No. 2 Wohnflaeche", min = 0, max = 20, step = 1, value = a),

  actionButton("residuen", "Zeige Residuen an") 

)


# Scatterplott

renderPlot({ 
  library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(mietspiegel, aes(y=nm, x=wfl)) +
    geom_abline(intercept = input$b, slope = input$a, colour = "red") + # Add inear regression line     
    geom_point(shape=1) + # Use hollow circles
    xlab("Flaeche") + # changed Fläche to Flaeche :)
    ylab("Price")
}) 


# Two ways of showing residual plots  when the button "Resample" is pressed:

# (i) Easy way - use conditionalPanel 
# conditionalPanel(
#   condition = "input.residuen !== 0", 
#   list(
#     hr(),
#     h3("Residuen"),
#     plotOutput("residuals"),
#     hr()
#   )
# )
# 
# output$residuals <- renderPlot({
#     par(mfrow = c(2,2))
#       plot(mieten_regression)
#     par(mfrow = c(1,1))
# })

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# (ii) More difficlult but more powerful way - use render renderUI with a condition. 
# Using modulo operator you can show and hide plots by pressing 

uiOutput("dynamic_residuals")



output$dynamic_residuals <- renderUI({
  if ((input$residuen + 1) %% 2 == 0 ) { 
    return(list(
      hr(),
      h3("Residuen"),
      plotOutput("residuals"),
      hr()
    ))
  } else {
    return(NULL)
  }
})

output$residuals <- renderPlot({
    par(mfrow = c(2,2))
      plot(mieten_regression)
    par(mfrow = c(1,1))
})
# You can read it in this way:
#  - use renderPlot function that sends a plot to the plotOutput
#  - create "plotOutput" via "renderUI" and place it (together with hr and h3 tags) in the document but only if the button (input$residuen) is clicked. 

```



## Second part of your question 

<hr>


```{r, echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warnings=FALSE}

# define functions for two Errorfields    

mean_abs_diff <- function(a,b,x,y) {mean(abs(a * x + b - y))} # middle absolute changing from y
    mean_sqr_diff <- function(a,b,x,y) {sqrt(mean((a * x + b - y)^2))} # sqrt of the middle square changing from y
```



```{r, echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warnings=FALSE}


renderPrint({
  # Errors vs changings of a
  mad <- mean_abs_diff(input$a, input$b, mietspiegel$wfl, mietspiegel$nm)
  msd <- mean_sqr_diff(input$a, input$b,mietspiegel$wfl, mietspiegel$nm)

  cat(" Mean absolute difference: ", round(mad, 2), "\n", 
      "Mean squared difference:  ", round(msd, 2))
})


```





```{r, echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warnings=FALSE}

# To generate new plots depending on changing values of the sliders, again,
# wrap the code into renderPlot and replace "a" and "b" with "input$a" and "input$b"

# You also can use mfrow to combine all these plots into one

x <- seq(-50, 50, 1)

renderPlot({ 
  par(mfrow = c(2,2), mar = c(3,3,3,3))

  plot(x, sapply(x, function(y) mean_sqr_diff(input$a, input$a + y,mietspiegel$wfl, mietspiegel$nm)), 
         xlab = "additive changing of b (delta b)", ylab = "sqrt of the middle sqaure error", type = "l")


    plot(x, sapply(x, function(y) mean_abs_diff(input$a, input$a + y,mietspiegel$wfl, mietspiegel$nm)), 
         xlab = "additive changing of b (delta b)", ylab = "middle absolute error", type = "l")

      # Errors vs changings of b 

  x <- seq(-1, 1, 0.1)

  plot(x, sapply(x, function(y) mean_sqr_diff(input$a + y, input$b,mietspiegel$wfl, mietspiegel$nm)), 
           xlab = "additive changing of a (delta a)", ylab = "sqrt of the middle sqaure error", type = "l")


  plot(x, sapply(x, function(y) mean_abs_diff(input$a + y, input$b,mietspiegel$wfl, mietspiegel$nm)),
           xlab = "additive changing of a (delta a)", ylab = "middle absolute error", type = "l")
  par(mfrow = c(1,1))
})
```
````

Comment: thx it wirks now fine...can i send you a pm ?    ive got 2 special quests for the code...

Comment: how can i build a small red circle which marks the exact a or b error in the line diagramm (regression line)

Comment: I can't say I understand it correctly - do you mean that if, for example,  `Mean absolute difference:  723.04` then you want a small red dot in each of the four plots (base R plots) which depicts the value 723.04?

Comment: this and a red dot or red hollow circle in my linear regression diagramm...

Comment: and look i your mailcase ^^